# Create web setup installer for the UAT project Web Form., ASP.net, C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have no problem in rebuild the UAT file project. Rebuild UAT file project is a success and has no error. But once the UAT Web Setup has created, so to rebuild it got 1 failed. The error is :

> **ERROR:**
> File 'NdefLibrary.dll' targeting 'AMD64' is not compatible with the project's target platform 'x86'

[image: Error image]

How supposed to solve this? Already searched but no solution found.

Also has tried to change the compatibility platform under
*Build tab > Configuration Manager*, but the error still remain the same.